# Unable to write to Firebase from node.js

Tags: node.js

I am able to read from Firestore, but not able to write. Is something wrong in the code below?

```
var registrationToken = mobile.data().fcmToken;
console.log('FCM token =>', registrationToken);

var updateSingle = mobile.add({requestsFriendsPostedCreatedBy: true}).then(ref => {
     console.log('Added document with ID: ', ref.id);
});
```

The FCM token prints to the logs, but the add is giving the following error:

```
TypeError: mobile.add is not a function
    at snapshotFriend.forEach.mobile (/user_code/index.js:49:35)
    at QuerySnapshot.forEach (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:731:22)
    at usersRef.where.get.then.snapshotFriend (/user_code/index.js:36:24)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I did the following:

```
mobileRef = db.collection('users').doc(`${mobile.id}`).collection('requestsFriendsPosted');
var updateSingle = mobileRef.doc(`${createdBy}`).set({status: 'open'})
```

The trick was the `